# Is it possible to access this json data with JavaScript / Ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

{"4255":"Alpine 50W x 4 Apple® iPod®-Ready In-Dash CD Deck","4254":"Alpine 50W x 4 In-Dash     CD Deck with Detachable Faceplate","4251":"Alpine 50W x 4 Apple® iPod®-/Satellite Radio-/HD Radio-Ready Marine CD Deck","4256":"Alpine 50W x 4 Apple® iPod®-Ready In-Dash CD Deck","9839":"Boss Marine 10\" Marine Single-Voice-Coil 4-Ohm Subwoofer","12433":"Alpine Type R 10\" Dual-Voice-Coil 8-Ohm Subwoofer","12428":"Alpine 12\" Single-Voice-Coil 4-Ohm Subwoofer"}

Do I need to get my json data into another format, or is this suitable for accessing via ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most actual browsers support this method :

```
var json = JSON.parse('{"4255":"Alpine 50W x 4 Apple® iPod®-Ready In-Dash CD Deck","4254":"Alpine 50W x 4 In-Dash CD Deck with Detachable Faceplate","4251":"Alpine 50W x 4 Apple® iPod®-/Satellite Radio-/HD Radio-Ready Marine CD Deck","4256":"Alpine 50W x 4 Apple® iPod®-Ready In-Dash CD Deck","9839":"Boss Marine 10\" Marine Single-Voice-Coil 4-Ohm Subwoofer","12433":"Alpine Type R 10\" Dual-Voice-Coil 8-Ohm Subwoofer","12428":"Alpine 12\" Single-Voice-Coil 4-Ohm Subwoofer"}');
```